# HTML- How would i go about making a section appear below another section?

Tags: html, css

Hi all i've been teaching myself some HTML/CSS/JS and working on codecamp to do so and hit an issue with a tribute page, I feel like this has a relatively simple solution but I've been trying so many different options i've run out of ideas along with me being sleep deprived it is not helping.

**My issue:** I'm trying to move the section in red below into the green box, but any time I try something to change it, it will move the anchor tag section just over top of the picture, I do not want to make this a footer as i'll be using that later, i still would like this to be part of the body. I've tried using display:block or even the positions from absolute/relative, unless i've been putting them on the wrong areas it's been giving me the same problems. Thank you for taking the time to read all this.[image]

```css
header{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:5px double;
  font-size:2.5em;
}

body{
  background-color:#efdecd;
}

p{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:250;
}

div.picture{
  float:left;
  background-color: #f2f0e6;
  margin-right:5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#image{
  height:72%;
  width:72%;
}

figure{
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:-205px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
  
  <!-- Title -->
  <header>
    <h1 id="title"> Diogenes of Sinope</h1>
    <p>The cynic philosopher</p>
  </header>
  
  
  <main id="main">
    <!-- Picture w/ caption -->
 <div class=picture id="img-div">   
    <figure>
  <img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Waterhouse-Diogenes.jpg/800px-Waterhouse-Diogenes.jpg" alt="Diogenes" >
   <!-- Caption of picture -->  
  <figcaption id="img-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
</figure>
    </div> 
   
    <!-- Body of page -->
    <section id="tribute-info">
      <h2>Timeline of Diogene's Life</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <!-- Picture -->
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8EM_cfYcDjY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen alt="Diogenes video"></iframe>
    </section>
    
   <!-- Anchor tag link --> 
    <section class="links">
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <a id="tribute-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.ancient.eu/article/740/the-life-of-diogenes-of-sinope-in-diogenes-laertiu/">Learn more about Diogenes</a>
    </section>
  </main>
  
</body>
```

Comment: just a side note, should have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start and `html` element around the entire head and body. Also, would be good to have `meta` in the head area describing the viewport, charset - atleast. If you are using Visual studio code for coding, typing `!` and hitting `tab` auto-generates this for you. also, would recommend not making such things like `margin-right: -205px`, like you did for the `figure` element, just to make it smaller so your white background looks good. If the image, or the browser window, changes size it will go out of place again.

Comment: also, should restrain yourself from using so much `ID`. Keep in mind that ID's have to be unique. So if you gave an ID of `title` to your `h1` element in header, u shouldint give an ID of same name to any element regardless if it uses the exact same css style. Should use class instead. ID's are more... personal. Mostly going to use it for javascript.

Comment: Thank you for those tips, i'll try finding an alternate solution for the margin-right problem i caused, and i'll also keep note of the IDs point you made, the exercise i'm doing called for quite a few IDs to be added in and I think I just got a little carried away with them without realizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have floated the image, to the left of the page, using float:left. Until you clear this, everything coming after it, will be floated to the left.

You could try adding:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

in your HTML, between your #tribute-info section and .links section.

Then define .clearfix in your CSS as follows:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! I would also recommend that you check out CSS Grid and Flexbox, for really neat layout solutions.

Comment: Floats, in general, behave in ways that are unexpected at first. They have an excellent single use-case for wrapping text around an image (wrapping 'inline's around a 'block', basically). But, in the age of much better ways to solve the basic alignment problem (grid, flexbox, inline-block) they're best avoided for almost everything else, and I think CSS guides should de-emphasize them.

Answer (score 1):

use FLEX!

```css
header{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:5px double;
  font-size:2.5em;
}

body{
  background-color:#efdecd;
}

#main{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<body>

   <!-- Title -->
   <header>
      <h1 id="title"> Diogenes of Sinope</h1>
      <p>The cynic philosopher</p>
   </header>


   <main id="main">
      <!-- Picture w/ caption -->
      <div class=picture id="img-div">
         <figure>
            <img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Waterhouse-Diogenes.jpg/800px-Waterhouse-Diogenes.jpg" alt="Diogenes">
            <!-- Caption of picture -->
            <figcaption id="img-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
         </figure>
      </div>

      <!-- Body of page -->
      <section id="tribute-info">
         <h2>Timeline of Diogene's Life</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         <!-- Picture -->
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8EM_cfYcDjY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen alt="Diogenes video"></iframe>
      </section>
   </main>
      <!-- Anchor tag link -->
      <section class="links">
         <h2>hello</h2>
         <a id="tribute-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.ancient.eu/article/740/the-life-of-diogenes-of-sinope-in-diogenes-laertiu/">Learn more about Diogenes</a>
      </section>
   

</body>
```

Comment: This was also extremely useful and getting rid of a few lines in CSS this also worked!

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a CSS reset in-between:

```
/* CSS reset */
 body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
 html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 body {
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 100;
}
 fieldset {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     width: 200px;
}
 legend {
     padding: 0 10px;
```

Comment: Instead of naming EVERY. SINGLE. ELEMENT. like you did on your line 2, should just use a star `*` , just saying